# Getting the 2 lines above the current line in a text file C#

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a foreach loop and for each line I need to get the 2 previous lines and store them in a variable. How would I do this? I have tried figuring this out for so long.

File size about 5mb

My foreach loop:

```
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("DeadByDaylightCopy.log"))
        {
            if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TW"))
            {
                killer = "Wraith";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TR"))
            {
                killer = "Trapper";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> HK"))
            {
                killer = "Spirit";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> MK"))
            {
                killer = "Plague";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> FK"))
            {
                killer = "Pig";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> OK"))
            {
                killer = "GhostFace";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TN"))
            {
                killer = "Nurse";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> KK"))
            {
                killer = "Legion";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> BE"))
            {
                killer = "Huntress";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> TC"))
            {
                killer = "Billy";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> WI"))
            {
                killer = "Hag";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> GK"))
            {
                killer = "Clown";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> SD"))
            {
                killer = "Freddy";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> DO"))
            {
                killer = "Doctor";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> CA"))
            {
                killer = "Cannibal";
            }
            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> MM"))
            {
                killer = "Myers";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> UK"))
            {
                killer = "Deathslinger";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> SwedenKiller"))
            {
                killer = "Oni";
            }

            else if (line.Contains("LogCustomization: --> QK"))
            {
                killer = "Demogorgon";
            }
```

Ex. Text file

```
LogCustomization: --> TR_HEAD_03
LogCustomization: --> TR_TORSO_P01
LogCustomization: --> TR_LEGS_02
fsdfs
fsdfs
LogCustomization: --> KK_HEAD_04
LogCustomization: --> KK_BODY_P01
LogCustomization: --> KK_LEGS_P01
dfsdfs
LogCustomization: --> TW_HEAD02_LP01
LogCustomization: --> TW_BODY03_LP01
LogCustomization: --> TW_WEAPON07_P01
sfsdfs
LogCustomization: --> CM_HEAD_P01
LogCustomization: --> CM_TORSO_06 
LogCustomization: --> CM_LEGS_LP01
sdfsf
sdfsdf
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Store all the lines in a string array. The loop thru the array starting with i=0. So that you can access previous two lines by doing `arr[i-1]` and `arr[i-2]`

Comment: What does the text at the bottom ("//2short //2short", etc.) mean?

Comment: Can you show an example of the file that you are trying to read? Are the keywords tested in your loop present at 3 lines interval?

Comment: And how big is this file? ReadAllLine loads everything from the file and this could be very important to your memory loads and performances

Comment: @Steve post edited

Comment: What should happen if you find a match but there are no two previous lines? For example if _"LogCustomization: --> TR"_ appears as the first line in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change a lot of things in your actual code to resolve the problem.

First, store all your conditions in a Dictionary like this one

```
Dictionary<string, string> keywords = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        {"LogCustomization: --> TW", "Wraith"},
        {"LogCustomization: --> TR", "Trapper"},
        {"LogCustomization: --> Sw", "Oni"},
        ... add the other keys here ....
    };
```

In the dictionary you store as keys all the conditions that you want to test with the particular of the word "SwedenKiller" reduced to just two letters. In the dictionary value store the value that you want to use when you retrieve that particular line.

At this point your code could be reduced a lot with this

```
// Load all data in memory in the variable allData
var allData = File.ReadAllLines("");

// Loop using a normal loop. This will allow to use the variable x as an indexer
// to retrieve the lines before the current one....
for (int x = 0; x < allData.Length; x++)
{
    string line = allData[x];

    // Discard the lines that doesn't start with the LogCustomization words
    if (line.StartsWith("LogCustomization: --> "))
    {
        // Take the words and two more characters
        string sub = line.Substring(0, 22);

        // Check if the substring is listed in the keywords dictionary
        if (keywords.ContainsKey(sub))
        {
            // Take the value and ....
            string killer = keywords[sub];
            if (x > 0)
            {
                // Take the previous line (x-1)
                string prevLine = allData[x - 1];
                if (x > 1)
                {
                    // Take the previous previous line (x-2)
                    string prevprevLine = allData[x - 2];

                    // Here goes your real logic with kille e prev lines.
                    Console.WriteLine($"current={line}, prev={prevLine}, prevprev={prevprevLine}");
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, here is the code to get a line with 2 previous lines:

```
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("DeadByDaylightCopy.log");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var linesAnd2PreviousLines = lines[Math.Max(0, i - 2)..(i + 1)];
        }
```